# How to use doxygen to create a documentation (and call graphs) for ALL python files

Tags: python, doxygen

I have a complex python-selenium test suite (using py.test) in a folder, and I waht to use doxygen to generate a documentation of all files (and, more importantly, the call graphs of what method is calling what method etc.).

I have set

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
```

but still, when I do

```
doxygen .
```

the result contains only a single file residing in the current folder. The command ignores any other python script residing in subfolders.

Even when I specify a file from inside a subfolder, e.g.

```
doxygen selenium/test_nbrunall.py
```

the result is still the same.

How to include all files and packages from the subfolders?

Comment: Have you set the RECURSIVE tag as yes? @Alex

Comment: I just set that flag to YES, but the outcome is the same...

Comment: Yeah I've so far only used doxygen with C++. Where I gave the location of the src files through "INPUT" And then called "doxygen Doxyfile" command to make the make files and then with make I made the pdf's. I did however alzays get one pdf containing all subsystems and subfolders as chapters

Comment: Ah I have to specify INPUT inside the configuration file...

Comment: But I still do not have the 'class graph', i.e. where I see where some method is called from, as example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case a number of useful tags (inside the doxygen configuration file, default can be generated by means of `doxygen -g`), especially with not yet documented code:

- RECURSIVE
- EXTRACT_...
- HAVE_DOT (note that you need the graphviz dot program installed as well).
- CALL_GRAPH
- CALLER_GRAPH

Comment: Wow, not yet documented code.  But thanks, I think I am getting now closer to what I really want...

Comment: I said it was easy ;-)

Comment: Yes, I have to agree, somewhat easy. I will play a bit more with the tags..